# How do I use a batch script variable in my Python program?

Tags: python, batch-file

How do I use a batch script variable in my Python program?

Comment: Please post some code

Answer (score 0):

if you want save this variable:

```
:\> python your.py >> result.txt
```

or use it:

```
:\> python your.py | todo
```